# Swiper/vue useSwiper() doesn't work, empty value undefined

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I have created my navigation and want to use the `useSwiper` method to control the buttons, but the method is empty. In the sandbox, I created an example that completely repeats my code. Normal navigation works, but when I want to use my buttons I get an error. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-vue-navigation-forked-733qyz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A24%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A24%7D%5D)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSwiper` hook must be used in components which are inside of the Swiper. In your case `swiper` is `undefined`.

You can get `swiper` from `onSwiper` event [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-vue-navigation-forked-oqtfj5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A10%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A31%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D):

```
<template>
  <Swiper
    @swiper="onSwiper"
    :navigation="true"
    :modules="modules"
    class="mySwiper"
  >
    <div>
      <button @click.stop="slider.slidePrev()">prev</button>
      <button @click.stop="slider.slideNext()">next</button>
    </div>

    <Swiper-slide>Slide 1</Swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </Swiper>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
import { Navigation } from "swiper";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";

const modules = [Navigation];
const slider = ref(null);
const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
  slider.value = swiper;
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work out. Thanks.