# How to use useSwiper hook in vueJS?

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I want to use a custom prev and next button elements, therefore I made the .swiper-button.next and .swiper-button.prev.
However, in the documentation is written that I need only to attach a click method to those elements and that's it, like `@click="sw.slideNext()"`

When I import the `useSwiper` and make a new const like `const sw = useSwiper()` then in the console I got some issue `Vue warn]: injection "swiper" not found.` and when i click on `.swiper-button.next`, then I get an error `nnot read properties of undefined (reading 'slideNext')`

With the default arrows which I get with the `navigation` and `:modules='modules'` property, it slieds as it should, but I need a custom design button, and those default blue arrow I can't owerwrite with css, it's just doesn't work, therefore are the custom buttons.

Here is the code:

```
<script setup>
import { Navigation } from 'swiper';
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import {ref, watch} from "vue";
import {useRoomStore} from "../stores/RoomStore.js";

defineEmits(['openRoom'])
const props = defineProps({room: Object})

const roomStore = useRoomStore()

const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
  console.log(swiper)
};

const onSlideChange = () => {
  console.log('slide change');
};

const sw = useSwiper()


const modules = [Navigation]

const activeRoomIdx = ref(null)

watch(() => props.room, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  if(!newVal){
    activeRoomIdx.value = null
  }
})

</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Rooms</h3>
    <div class="rooms-container">
      <span class="swiper-button prev"></span>
      <swiper
          :modules="modules"
          :slides-per-view="6"
          :space-between="12"
          @swiper="onSwiper"
          @slideChange="onSlideChange"
          navigation
      >
        <swiper-slide v-for="(room, idx) in roomStore.rooms">
          <div class="room-container" :class="{active: activeRoomIdx === idx}" @click="() => {
            activeRoomIdx = idx;
            $emit('openRoom', room);
          }">
            {{ room.name }}
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
      </swiper>
      <span class="swiper-button next" @click="sw.slideNext()"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swiper/vue useSwiper() doesn't work, empty value undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949883/swiper-vue-useswiper-doesnt-work-empty-value-undefined)